# MATLAB: Import a very large file in batches

Tags: matlab, csv, import, batch-processing

I am trying to import a large csv file (215000X3) in batches of 50. After looking around I had people suggest to use 'textscan'. I did it using the following code

```
N = 50;
fid = fopen('PIDFile.csv');
formatSpec = '%s %s %s';
k=0;
while ~feof(fid)
    k = k+1;
    block = textscan(fid, formatSpec, N, 'Delimiter',',');
end
```

After running this part of the code, I get 'block' to be as follows:

```
34X1 cell    34X1 cell     34X1 cell
```

the file being imported is a regular csv file. I have been looking at fread, fscan, csvread etc but haven't come across examples/sloutions which offer block imports. Any suggestions/comments would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
H

Comment: If you are using one of the recent versions MATLAB (e.g., R2014b), you can check out "datastore", which supports partial reading of the CSV files: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-and-analyze-data-in-a-tabulartextdatastore.html

Comment: I'm using R2014a which apparently does not have the 'datastore' function in its library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, All I had to do was:

```
block = cell2mat(textscan(fid, formatSpec, N, 'Delimiter',','));
```

and that solved the issue!